# Парсер XML для создания игр

Tags: c++, xml, парсер, разработка-игр

Я хочу сделать игру, ее уровни будут хранится в формате XML точнее говоря там будет для каждого тайла прописан тег и как ни странно файлы будут массивные. Какой парсер стоит использовать для большой информации потому-что в игре важна ее оптимизация?

Comment: FTL: Faster Than Light использует RapidXML. Но есть в особо тяжёлых случаях вас не вытянет "сырая скорость" парсера и вам надо будет пересматривать подход к хранению данных.

Comment: Один из лучших xml-парсеров - TinyXml-2. Но как ни крути, корректный парсер xml не может быть быстрым, т.к. необходимо строить дерево элементов. Для повышения производительности можно использовать какой-нибудь потоковый парсер, читающий xml последовательно, но возникает вопрос - не лучше ли использовать JSON?

Comment: Как правило, парсер работает только при старте игры/уровня или при серьезных изменениях в процессе игры.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы порекомендовал [TinyXML-2](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml2/). Он в несколько раз быстрее первой версии и по нему есть [хорошая документация](http://leethomason.github.io/tinyxml2/). Не знаю, отличается ли интерфейс второй версии от первой, поскольку только что узнал о новой версии, но по первой точно есть довольно много материалов

Answer (score 0):

Использование XML хорошо и удобно на этапе проектирования и создания игры.
Для релиза, если есть проблема со скоростью парсинга, - переходите на бинарные данные.
Можете хранить массивные данные в XML в виде блоба в base64 и доставать распаковывать их при старте.